# React app is not starting after npm start

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1147:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rajan/Documents/wendor-projects/wendor-react-admin/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I research and found to update react-scripts. [Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20503#issuecomment-586743378)

```
npm install react-scripts@3.4.0
```

But still this error is not going.

I also try to delete node module and install it once by npm and other by yarn 

Both cases have same out put. I am on Ubuntu

Comment: Also delete `package-lock.json`

Comment: When i shifted from yarn i did not have package-lock.json

Comment: can you add your webpack configuration?

Comment: If it's an open source project please push it to github, I'll clone and see what's the matter. I'll try my best.

Comment: sorry but It is not opensource @Tanzeel

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez stackoverflow not allowing this much words to get uploaded. it is same  as create react app